# I have to shift the label of the angle according to the length of the label (20deg), it can also be (x+20)

Tags: math, geometry, discrete-mathematics, jsxgraph

I have to shift the label of the angle according to the length of the label (20deg), it can also be (x+20). I know the coordinates of three-point and midpoint coordinates of the arc. I want to calculate the different midpoint of the angled label to shift it upward in all the directions.

[image: Follow the link to the image]

Comment: How do you realize this contruction: with arcs or with angles?

Comment: I calculated the midpoint of the arc by taking the angle from x-axis

Comment: @AlfredWassermann I calculated the midpoint of the arc by taking the angle from x-axis

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the angle element. Then, the placement is done automatically:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});

var p1 = board.create('point', [0,2]);
var p2 = board.create('point', [0,0]);
var p3 = board.create('point', [-2,0.2]);

var a = board.create('angle', [p1, p2, p3], {
  radius: 1, 
  name: function() {
    return JXG.Math.Geometry.trueAngle(p1, p2, p3).toFixed(1) + '°';
  }});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/eys9qpn1/.

Alternatively, you can set the attributes `anchorX` and `anchorY` of the text elements containing the angle values, see https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Text.html#anchorX.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gwKAtlk It will again overlap, if I increase the label length

Comment: For the time being, you probably need to do some fine-tuning by hand. Is this possible? If yes, you might also consider to use `display:"internal", rotate:90` and rotate the texts.